# Can I mock a function return that is called within another function call in a Python Test?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there a way to mock a function return that is called within another function call? For example:

```
def bar():
    return "baz"

def foo():
    return bar()

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_code(self):
        # hijack bar() here to return "bat" instead
        assert(foo() == "bat")
```

I've tried using `@mock.patch` but have found that it only allows me to mock the function I'm calling, not a function that will be called as a result of calling a a different function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Generic Patch**

[`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) does exactly what my other answer suggested out of the box. You can add as many `@patch` annotations as you need, and the objects you select will be patched:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def bar():
    return "baz"

def foo():
    return bar()

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch(__name__ + '.bar', lambda: 'bat')
    def test_code(self):
        assert(foo() == "bat")
```

In this configuration, the function `bar` will be reinstated once `test_code` completes. If you want the same patch to apply to all test cases in your class, annotate the whole class:

```
@patch(__name__ + '.bar', lambda: 'bat')
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_code(self):
        assert(foo() == "bat")
```

**Patch Globals**

You can also [`unittest.mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict) on your global namespace for the same result:

```
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.dict(globals(), {'bar': lambda: 'bat'})
    def test_code(self):
        assert(foo() == "bat")
```

Comment: This is great. Did not realize you could do that with Patch. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can write a context manager to temporarily swap out objects in the global namespace:

```
class Hijack:
    def __init__(self, name, replacement, namespace):
        self.name = name
        self.replacement = replacement
        self.namespace = namespace

    def __enter__(self):
        self.original = self.namespace[self.name]
        self.namespace[self.name] = self.replacement

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.namespace[self.name] = self.original
```

You can call your mock function with the hijacked method:

```
def bar():
    return "baz"

def bar_mock():
    return "bat"

def foo():
    return bar()

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_code(self):
        with Hijack('bar', bar_mock, globals()):
            assert(foo() == "bat")
```

This is a pretty general approach that can be used outside of unit testing. In fact, it is pretty simple to generalize this to work on any mutable object that can be represented as some sort of mapping:

```
class Hijack:
    def __init__(self, name, replacement, namespace, getter=None, setter=None):
        self.name = name
        self.replacement = replacement
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.getter = type(namespace).__getitem__ if getter is None else getter
        self.setter = type(namespace).__setitem__ if setter is None else setter

    def __enter__(self):
        self.original = self.getter(self.namespace, self.name)
        self.setter(self.namespace, self.name, self.replacement)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.setter(self.namespace, self.name, self.original)
```

For classes and other objects, you would use `getter=getattr` and `setter=setattr`. For situations where `None` is preferable to `KeyError`, you can use `getter=dict.get`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could use pytest `seattr` method of `monkeypatch` fixture. For the first arguments, it accepts an object to be patched or a string will be interpreted as a dotted import path, with the last part being the attribute name:

```
# foo_module.py
def bar():
    return "baz"


def foo():
    return bar()
```

```
# test_foo.py
from foo_module import foo


def test_foo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('foo_module.bar', lambda: 'bat')
    assert foo() == "bat"
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that out. Will prob stick to the patch approach above but this is good to know regardless. Thanks